# Displaying or redirecting a shell's job control messages

Tags: linux, shell, signals, zsh

**TL;DR**

All job control / crash messages are hidden when they occur within a function. I go into more detail below, but [@Barmar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1491895/barmar) has pointed out that this issue can be reproduced by running a crashing binary inside of a function, e.g:

```
crun() { 
  /tmp/faulty $1 $2 $3
}
```

---

I've defined a function in my `.zshrc` to compile & run source code with the function below:

```
crun() {
    local file=$1
    shift
    local exepath="$(mktemp)"

    if [[ $file =~ "\.c$" ]]; then
        gcc -g -Wall $file -o $exepath || return $?
    else
        echo "no filetype detected"
        return 126
    fi

    $exepath "$@"
}
```

Which can be called in this fashion:

```
% crun source.cc arg_1 arg_2
```

This works for normal programs, but has the problem that the shell's job control messages, such as those generated from a segfault, do not appear.

As an example:

```
% echo 'int main=0;' >> /tmp/faulty.c # a crashing c program
% crun faulty.c
% # no output generated
```

Whereas the equivalent interactive commands would generate this:

```
% g++ faulty.c -o /tmp/faulty && /tmp/faulty
[1] 2894 segmentation fault (core dumped) #  zsh's job control output for SIGSEGV
```

Is there any way to display these messages for a crashing executable whose path is dynamically calculated? Ideally without writing your own trap/signal handlers + `exec`, using `sh -c "$exepath $@"`, or writing a totally new `system(3)` wrapper entirely)

Comment: I don't understand the aside. You say that it works properly when running `crun` within the shell itself. How else are you running it when it doesn't work?

Comment: @Barmar You are right, that was totally confusing, I've removed it. Basically it *is* possible to get the job control messages by running `crun` inside of another file and running the generated binary with `exec` (because the shell's process image is replaced with a program which segfaults, which the parent shell catches it). I included the aside just for some context on the difference between interactive and non-interactive execution and how that can be relevant.

Comment: When I try your function, I always get "No filetype detected" -- there's a problem with the `if`. When I take that out, I get the segmentation fault message from the shell.

Comment: `faulty.c:1:5: warning: ‘main’ is usually a function [-Wmain]
Segmentation fault`

Comment: Ahh, I'm trying it in `bash`, didn't notice that you're asking about `zsh`.

Comment: @Barmar No, it was my fault for not being clear (I wrote it in such a way to make it ambiguous). Thank you so much for taking the time to test this.

Comment: The problem has nothing to do with variables. It appears that program crash messages are simply suppressed when they occur in a function. Define a simply function like `crun() { /tmp/faulty; }` and it won't show the messasge.

Comment: Seems like this should be a known issue, but I can't seem to find it. Whenever I google things like "zsh segmentation fault function", all I get are posts about zsh crashing.

Comment: What version of gcc are you using? I get nothing but 

`$ g++ faulty.c -o faulty

faulty.c:1:10: error: expected ‘,’ or ‘;’ at end of input

 int main=0

          ^

$`

Comment: You are right @JesseAdelman , I've modified that line to include a semicolon at the end (although the problem still persists with any crashing binary).

Comment: It's important to note what actually prints the segfault message: it is the calling shell. I think you may find some help with this other question's answer here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/257616/145209

Comment: @JesseAdelman Yes, those messages generated by the shell in response to `SIGSEGV`/segfaults and other errors are called 'Job Control Messages' as indicated above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get `zsh` to print the segmentation fault message from the job if you start it as a background job and then immediately bring it to the foreground.

```bash
"$exepath" "$@" &
fg
```

This will cause `zsh` to print out messages for signals on the job started for `$exepath`.

The downside is that you will get a little bit more than you bargained for:

```
% crun faulty.c
faulty.c:1:5: warning: ‘main’ is usually a function [-Wmain]
 int main=0;
     ^~~~
[2] 2080
[2]  - running    "$exepath" "$@"
zsh: segmentation fault (core dumped)  "$exepath" "$@"
```

But as shown, you will get the segfault messages printed in the terminal.

Because the messages are printed by the interactive shell, not the failing process, the job messages won't get redirected should you try to redirect `stdout` or `stderr`.

So on the one hand, should you try to take useful output out of your running process and redirect it somewhere else, you don't need to worry about the job messages getting in the way. But this also means you won't get the segfault message should you try to redirect it by redirecting `stderr`.

Here's a demonstration of this effect, with line breaks added in-between commands for clarity:

```
% crun good.c > test
[2] 2071
[2]  - running    "$exepath" "$@"

% cat test
Hello, world!

% crun faulty.c 2>test
[2] 2092
[2]  - running    "$exepath" "$@"
zsh: segmentation fault (core dumped)  "$exepath" "$@"

% cat test
faulty.c:1:5: warning: ‘main’ is usually a function [-Wmain]
 int main=0;
     ^~~~
```

For more information, see [`zsh`'s documentation on jobs and signals](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Jobs-_0026-Signals.html). You can also poke around [the C file where the magic happens](https://github.com/zsh-users/zsh/blob/a955065cda3dcaa80058520ba55dc0bf5c8d3f08/Src/jobs.c).