# csh wait command output to a file

Tags: linux, csh

How can I get wait command output to a variable to file.

```
#!/bin/csh

sleep 2 &
sleep 3 &
wait > out.txt
```

output:

```
# ./abc.sh
[1] 30540
[2] 30541
[2]    Done                   sleep 3
[1]  + Done                   sleep 2
```

out.txt file is blank.

Comment: What output would you expect? There *is* no output from `wait`. The job control messages do not come from the `wait` command, but from the controlling shell (and even then only when job control is enabled, which it isn't by default in noninteractive scripts).

Comment: ...well, not in bash. Why do you have this tagged both bash and csh? They're completely unrelated shells, and not compatible with each other at all.

Comment: Excepting : [2]    Done                   sleep 3
[1]  + Done                   sleep 2 in a out.txt

Comment: Right; those messages aren't output from `wait` itself, but from the shell's job control routines. They'd still be displayed if the children exited even if `wait` were never run.

Comment: Incidentally, there's a zsh-specific answer to this over at [Redirecting or displaying a shell's job control messages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45023243/displaying-or-redirecting-a-shells-job-control-messages)

Comment: To prove what I was saying, consider `sleep 2 & sleep 3 & sleep 4` -- there's no `wait`, but you still get your `Done`s, because they *aren't output from* `wait` (or `sleep` either).

Comment: The only purpose that `wait` serves is to keep the script from exiting before the background processes finish. It doesn't print the messages.

Comment: Why are you writing a script in csh in the first place? It's well known to be the worst shell for scripting. See http://www.faqs.org/faqs/unix-faq/shell/csh-whynot/