# ZSH Function Behavior? (Running C++)

Tags: shell, zsh

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    cout << 5 << endl;
    vector<int> v; cout << v[-1];
}
```

I am using `zsh` on Mac. When I compile and run `A.cpp` (shown above) with `g++-9 -o A A.cpp && ./A`, the result is as follows:

```
5
zsh: segmentation fault  ./A
```

However, when I define a function in `.zshenv` (shown below) and run it, only `5` is printed.

```
RUN() {
    g++-9 -o A A.cpp && ./A
}
```

What should I do to make the segmentation fault message also display?

Comment: Possible duplicate? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45023243/displaying-or-redirecting-a-shells-job-control-messages

Comment: This question seems to be about zsh. To avoid distractions about what the C++ code does, you could replace the C++ program with the C program `#include <signal.h> int main(void) { raise(SIGSEGV); }`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in John's link ([Displaying or redirecting a shell's job control messages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45023243/displaying-or-redirecting-a-shells-job-control-messages)) it seems that adding `& fg` suffices.